# Catch Exception in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

We are using AngularJS 1.6 and has written below directive to submit form.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function formSubmitDirective(cookieService) {
        return {
            require: "form",
            link: function ($scope, $el) {
                var csrf = cookieService.csrfTokenCookie();
                $el[0].querySelector('#csrf').value = csrf;
                $el[0].submit();
            }
        };
    }

    formSubmitDirective.$inject = ['cookieService'];

    angular
        .module('csmDirectives')
        .directive('csmFormSubmit', formSubmitDirective);

}());
```

Here we are using it:

```
<div ng-if="vm.autoLogout">
    <form csm-form-submit role="form" action="/app/logout" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="_csrf" ng-value="vm.csrfToken"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that applications generates 403 error during POST request sometimes. In that case, I want to catch that exception and want to move the page to below url:

```
 localhost:8080/app/index.html#timeout
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your submit call:

```
link: function ($scope, $el) {
  var csrf = cookieService.csrfTokenCookie();
  $el[0].querySelector('#csrf').value = csrf;
  try {
    $el[0].submit();
  } catch(e) {
    // You would have to define a timeout-state 'state', assuming you're
    // using states though;
    state.go('timeout-state');
  }
},
controller: function($state, $stateParams) {
  var scope = this;
  scope.state = $state;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but you would need the controller in there to gain access to $state. All of this assumes you use some kind of $state (could be $routeProvider instead), but if you're using Angular1.6 it's a good bet you are.

Comment: It looks like a real form post is occurring, so I'm not sure you can catch the error like this